# AEM page with rich text and image

Tags: aem, rte

I am using AEM 6.0 and want authors to create page using a template having

1. Page  headline
2. Page  sub headline
3. Page rich text
4. An image
5. Page rich text

Similar page - [Page with image & RTE](http://www.roche.com/research_and_development/what_we_are_working_on/oncology/cancer-immunotherapy/an-introduction-to-cancer-immunotherapy.htm)

I am planning to use AEM RTE for rich text and as RTE does not provide any option to inset image, i can do one of these

- Upgrade RTE to embed image but it will have issues with responsiveness
- Create page with multiple RTE and image components to render above output.

Does anyone know best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed layout with responsive capabilities you are better off using templates just for simplicity. By fixed layout I am assuming your page will have fixed content location for images and text (guessing from your template details)

Modifying RTE for responsive image insertion on an arbitrary location will not render a good HTML unless you override a lot of RTE functionality. This will be a pain and counter-productive for the use case.

A mid-way alternative is to make a custom image with text (text and image control) where you allow the user to enter text and select and image separately and then provide additional layount options (image position) and responsive customisation.

One more flexible option is to use acs-commons grid layout control to use different text and image controls while letting a grid based css framework (e.g. bootstrap) take care of responsive aspects of the site.

Hope these ideas help you.

Comment: Thanks i.net. I am using template where authors can drag and drop RTE & image component. It will help to retail responsiveness.

Comment: If your templates are responsive (like build with some grid system or other responsive methodologies) then I would recommend separating out text from images as it gives you more options and less headache. Embedding images in RTE and trying to make it responsive is a lot of work in my experience and you normally end up rewriting the whole RTE control from scratch. This is because RTE, inherently, is not based on any responsive layout design and mostly contain inline elements and styles.

Comment: I agree so keeping image & RTE separate at template level.